# How can i take a screenshot in Appium Robot Framework?

Tags: ubuntu, appium, robotframework, screenshot

I'm runnning a basic test to learn Appium using Robot Framework but i'm having some problems to capture screenshots.

Thats the error:

```
KEYWORD Screenshot . Take Screenshot validate-terms.jpg, 80%
Documentation:  
Takes a screenshot in JPEG format and embeds it into the log file.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20210409 15:51:08.479 / 20210409 15:51:08.486 / 00:00:00.007
15:51:08.484    WARN    Taking screenshot failed: OSError: X connection failed: error 5
Make sure tests are run with a physical or virtual display. 
15:51:08.486    INFO
```

My question is, what more i need to do to take a simple screenshot using Appium with robot framework in ubuntu ?

More info:

- I'm using physical device
- I'm running on ubuntu
- I'm using Azure DevOps Pipelines to execute the script

And more info:

Basic script to reproduce:

```
***Settings***

Library         AppiumLibrary
Library         Screenshot

***Test Cases***
Trying to take a screenshot
    Wait Until Element Is Visible               id=com.anything.qa:id/test_id
    Take Screenshot                             validate-terms.jpg      80%
```

Basic Azure DevOps Pipeline info:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python37:
      python.version: '3.7'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'pip install robotframework robotframework-appiumlibrary robotframework-screencaplibrary'
  displayName: 'Robot Install'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' and it worked perfectly!